Umlauts not displaying correctly after a few requests in Angular application with Node.js Express backend and MySQL
I’m working on a full-stack application consisting of an Angular frontend and a Node.js Express backend. The backend communicates with a MariaDB database using the mysql2 library.
Everything worked fine for a long time, but about a week ago, I started noticing an issue where umlauts and special characters were displayed correctly only for the first few requests. After a few successful queries, the umlauts start showing up incorrectly (as � (U+FFFD) or other gibberish).
Restarting the Node.js application temporarily fixes the issue, but it reappears after a few more requests.
Question: What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that umlauts and other special characters are consistently displayed correctly in my Angular application with a Node.js Express backend? Is there something specific about mysql2 or connection pooling that I might be missing?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Charset Configuration:

I’ve ensured that the charset is set to utf8mb4 in both the MySQL database and the connection pool in the Node.js Express backend:
const pool = mysql2.createPool({ 
   connectionLimit: 10,
   host: "localhost",
   user: "dbuser",
   password: "password",
   database: "dbname",
   charset: "utf8mb4",
});



Set charset for each connection:

I’ve tried forcing the charset with SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' after establishing each connection.


Nginx Proxy:

I checked my Nginx configuration to ensure it’s passing through UTF-8 correctly:
http { include mime.types; default_type application/json; charset utf-8; }





a connction wouldn't change its collation /charcter set, maybe you made a new session with another character set collation

Try making a [mcve]

Are you using MySQL or MariaDB? Your question does not make this clear. Please query SELECT VERSION(); and report exactly what it says. It's important to be clear because MySQL and MariaDB are not the same product, are often not compatible, and a solution for one may not be supported by the other.

Here’s the output from the SELECT VERSION(); query:
10.11.8-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.24.04.1
